# how long does it take for a photo-conductor to become a conductor when exposed to light?

Tags: visible-light, photons, order-of-magnitude

How fast does a photo-conductor reach full conductivity when exposed to the appropriate wavelength of light? How fast does it cease to conduct when the radiation ceases? It might vary, so I could also use the general order of magnitude or range, also if photoconductors vary too wildly in this regard, could you describe a photoconductor that reaches full capacity and back again in less than a 30th of a picosecond? I'm working on a device that needs to detect pulses of light in the gigahertz range

Comment: Gigahertz is pretty easy with pin diodes.

Comment: I think your limiting factor here might be the capacitance and inductance around the photoconductor rather than its internal response time.